# The client on Spring Boot does not switch to Keylock for authorization

Tags: java, spring-security, keycloak

I'm trying to reproduce an example of working with Keylock.
I connect to Keycloak using an adapter.

Here is the application code

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/anonymous/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class SampleController {

    @GetMapping("/user")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
    public String getUserInfo() {
        return "user info";
    }

    @GetMapping("/admin")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public String getAdminInfo() {
        return "admin info";
    }
}
```

These are Spring settings

```
server:
  port: ${SERVER_PORT:11002}
spring: 
  application.name: ${APPLICATION_NAME:spring-security-keycloak}
keycloak:
  auth-server-url: http://10.15.68.8:8484/auth
  realm: first-test
  resource: first-login
  public-client: true
```

pom.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.akazakov.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-keycloak-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Demo Keycloak Adapter</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot and Keycloak</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
                <version>12.0.3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Keycloak itself is launched in Docker at this address http://10.15.68.8:8484

I open the page in the browser

```
http://localhost:11002/api/admin
```

and instead of

```
http://10.15.68.8:8484/auth
```

I get on

```
http://localhost:11002/sso/login
```

moreover, it turns out to be looping, i.e. there is a constant transition to this address.

And in the Spring application, an error crashes with each such transition

```
2022-09-28 16:09:53.661 ERROR 74584 --- [io-11002-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing /sso/login

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/security/acl/Group
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.createPrincipalFactory(KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:96) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-12.0.3.jar:12.0.3]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.createSessionTokenStore(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:262) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-12.0.3.jar:12.0.3]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.getTokenStore(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:251) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-12.0.3.jar:12.0.3]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.getTokenStore(KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:106) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-12.0.3.jar:12.0.3]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.checkKeycloakSession(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:228) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-12.0.3.jar:12.0.3]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.invoke(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:180) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-12.0.3.jar:12.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:887) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1684) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.security.acl.Group
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I think you forgot to configure the spring security to avoid double bean registration https://www.keycloak.org/docs/12.0/securing_apps/index.html#avoid-double-bean-registration, and can you share why you need your rest api endpoint to be a public client?

Comment: I'm just starting to learn Spring Security in conjunction with Keycloak. This is a ready-made example of using Spring Security, I have not changed anything in the code and I present it as it is.

Answer (score 3):

**Do not use Keycloak adapter for Spring**. [It is (very) deprecated](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187). Use `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` instead. [See here how](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials).

Your `@RestControllers` form resource-server(s). From OAuth2 resource-server point of view, a request is authorized when it has a **Bearer `Authorization` header**. It does not matter:

- which of accepted authorization-server issued that token (in multi-tenant scenarios)
- how that token was acquired:

  - a user is authorized with authorization-code flow (which might invole multifactor authentication)
  - a program is authenticated with client-credentials flow
  - even a device can be authorized with device flow.

Put login, logout, access-token acquiring and refreshing, etc. in clients. Choose an OpenID lib for your client-side framework to do that (or test with Postman which has integrated tooling for getting OAuth2 access-tokens).